# Diamond inheritence - Inheriting from an abstract class and also a concrete class than implements a shared based class

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

Please Consider:

IReferenceCounting is a pure abstract class, with methods AddRef and RemoveRef

```
virtual void AddRef() noexcept = 0;
virtual void RemoveRef() noexcept = 0;
```

I did not build this class, nor can I change it.

Now I have another class, which I did build, called ISoundComponent that inherits from IReferenceCounting. Class ISoundComponent is also abstract (for a start it doesn't contain a definition for AddRef or Release).

As every component that inherits from IReferenceCounted will need to implement AddRef and RemoveRef, there exists ReferenceCountedImpl, which inherits from IReferenceCounted. I did not build this class and I cannot change it.

Finally, I have another class I did build, say SoundDiagnostics, which inherits from ISoundComponent and ReferenceCountedImpl

Many have you have already seen it - I have a diamond inheritance problem. By not providing my own AddRef and RemoveRef, and instead using ReferenceCountedImpl, means I would need ISoundComponent and ReferenceCountedImpl to inherit virtually from IReferenceCounted... correct?

Unfortunately I cannot edit ReferenceCountedImpl only ISoundComponent . This is because IReferenceCounting  and ISoundComponent live across many projects in our codebase but ReferenceCountedImpl lives inside only a single project (the same project SoundDiagnostics lives). This makes sense, as a project can decide on how it wants to implement the IReferenceCounting, and we should be able to reuse it inside different classes in that project.

Unfortunately, as I cannot go and edit ReferenceCountedImpl, I cannot build this, due to the diamond inheritance problem (SoundDiagnostics won't know whether to call ReferenceCountedImpl::AddRef or ISoundComponent ::AddRef).

I feel like I'm barking up the wrong tree, missing something obvious, getting caught up in the details of virtual inheritance and/or and my design is messed up. The codebase organization should be agnostic to this problem. Can anyone give me some guidance on how this should be architected? I don't think ReferenceCountedImpl inheriting virtually from IReferenceCounted is the solution - e.g. there are performance reasons to consider when doing this.

Interested to learn how to tackle this.

EDIT:

```
// available across all projects in code base
class IReferenceCounted
{
    virtual void AddRef() = 0;
    virtual void RemoveRef() = 0;
};

// available across a few select projects in the codebase (ones that wish to use some kind of sound component)
class ISoundComponent : public virtual IReferenceCounted
{
    virtual void Play() const = 0;
};

// available within one specific project, SoundDiagnostics. I cannot modify this
class ReferenceCountedImpl : public IReferenceCounted
{
    void AddRef() override
    {
        m_refcount++;
    }

    void RemoveRef() override
    {
        if (--m_refcount == 0)
        {
            delete this;
        }

    }

    int m_refcount = 0;
};

// available within one specific project, SoundDiagnostics.
class SoundDiagnostics : public ISoundComponent, public ReferenceCountedImpl
{
    void Play() const override
    {
        return;
    }

    void RunDiagnostics()
    {

    }
};

// function within my SoundDiagnostics project
int main()
{
    SoundDiagnostics soundDiagnostics;
    return 0;
}
```

Trying to compile this will produce

> object of abstract class type "SoundDiagnostics" is not allowed:
>   pure virtual function "IReferenceCounted::AddRef" has no overrider
>   pure virtual function "IReferenceCounted::RemoveRef" has no overrider

If ReferenceCountedImpl inherits virtually from IReferenceCounted then this code compiles successfully.

Comment: I feel there is a solution to your problem, but your description is still too abstract for me to get a clear handle on it. Would you try posting some code snippets and marking which ones you can change and which you can't?

Comment: `ReferenceCountedImpl` exists in only one project, *your* project, and you *can't* edit it. `IComponentPublicHeader` exists over many projects, and you *can* edit it. This makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Omnifarious, change the names be more concrete and added a code snippet

Comment: @Beta, I've changed the names to be more concrete. Maybe it's a little more clear how such a scenario can arrive. In project containing SoundDiagnostics, someone decided to implement a concrete reference counting class. SoundDiagnostics lives is a big project with many classes which inherit from IReferenceCounted.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to turn your description into code. It works.

```
class IReferenceCounting {
public:
    virtual void AddRef() const noexcept = 0;
    virtual void RemoveRef() const noexcept = 0;
};
class IComponentPublicHeader :public virtual IReferenceCounting {};
class ReferenceCountedImpl :public virtual IReferenceCounting {
public:
    void AddRef() const noexcept override {};
    void RemoveRef() const noexcept override {};
};
class MyAmazingClass : IComponentPublicHeader, ReferenceCountedImpl {
    MyAmazingClass() {
        AddRef();// ReferenceCountedImpl::AddRef
    }
};
```

Update:I read your code snippet.If AddRef and RemoveRef is public,You can try to implement your class like this.

```
class SoundDiagnostics : public ISoundComponent, public ReferenceCountedImpl
{
    void Play() const override
    {
        return;
    }
    void AddRef() override
    {
        ReferenceCountedImpl::AddRef();
    }

    void RemoveRef() override
    {
        ReferenceCountedImpl::RemoveRef();
    }
    void RunDiagnostics()
    {

    }
};
```

If AddRef and RemoveRef is private,let ISoundComponent not inherit the IReferenceCounted.

```
class ISoundComponent
{
    virtual void Play() const = 0;
};
```

Comment: In your class declarations, `IComponentPublicHeader` and `ReferenceCountedImpl` inherit virtually. The OP implies that his do not, and states that he cannot change `ReferenceCountedImpl`.

Comment: Additionally, you probably want to inherit `ReferenceCountedImpl` virtually. It's the class that actually has some storage in it. I think everybody who inherits from `IReferenceCounting` is going to get the 'most derived' versions of `AddRef` and `RemoveRef`. But, I'm not sure if that's OK either because the OPs description isn't clear.

Comment: 郭一凡, Beta is right. Please see my updated/edit question and code snippet. @Omnifarious, I'm not convinced you do want to inherit virtually from IReferenceCounted inside ReferenceCountedImpl, as that requires an indirection. Any existing classes which inherit from ReferenceCountedImpl have to pay this indirection cost.

Comment: also, @Omnifarious, inheriting virtually from ReferenceCountedImpl within SoundDiagnostics doesn't help anything, right?